# OpenGL Matrix Multiplier Tool

Tags: opengl, matrix-multiplication

Lets say I have 2 matrices in a 16 element array. Does anyone know of an online utility that will allow me to copy and paste the array in that format and get back the product.

Example:

```
GLfloat m1[16] = {v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, ..., v15};
GLfloat m2[16] = {v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, ..., v15};
```

Magic Web Page:
`m1 * m2 = {v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, ..., v15};` // This can be in any visual output.

I have tried to Google for such a thing but have had no success.

**AMEND**

Using GNU Octave / Qt Octave I get

```
proj =

   1.81066   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   2.41421   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000  -1.00000  -0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000  -1.00000   0.00000

>>> view = [1, -0, 0, -0; 0, 1, 0, -0; -0, -0, 1, -2; 0, 0, 0, 1]
view =

   1  -0   0  -0
   0   1   0  -0
  -0  -0   1  -2
   0   0   0   1

>>> model = [1, 0, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 0, 1]
model =

   1   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0
   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   1

>>> tmp= [1.81066, 0, 0, 0; 0, 2.41421, 0, 0; 0, 0, -1, 2; 0, 0, -1, 2]
tmp =

   1.81066   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   2.41421   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000  -1.00000   2.00000
   0.00000   0.00000  -1.00000   2.00000

>>> proj * view * model
ans =

   1.81066   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   2.41421   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000  -1.00000   2.00000
   0.00000   0.00000  -1.00000   2.00000

>>>
```

---

When using:

```
proj = [1.81066, 0, 0, 0; 0, 2.41421, 0, 0; 0, 0, -1, -0; 0, 0, -1, 0]
view = [1, -0, 0, -0; 0, 1, 0, -0; -0, -0, 1, -2; 0, 0, 0, 1]
model = [1, 0, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 0, 1]
tmp= [1.81066, 0, 0, 0; 0, 2.41421, 0, 0; 0, 0, -1, 2; 0, 0, -1, 2]
```

Comment: The two outputs are consistent. If you read across the rows you will see that the matrices are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com).

You would have to apply a bit of formatting to say that you are multiplying arrays, but something like this should work should produce the output you want:

```
{{0, 1}, {2, 3}} * {{1, 2},{3,4}}
```

If you want to have the input to be in exactly the format you have it, you will probably have to write it yourself. Wikipedia explains the [formula involved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29).

Comment: I kept Googling while I was waiting and came across GNU Octave. On the command line if I output my matrices as follows: 

proj = [1.81066, 0, 0, 0; 0, 2.41421, 0, 0; 0, 0, -1, -0; 0, 0, -1, 0]
view = [1, -0, 0, -0; 0, 1, 0, -0; -0, -0, 1, -2; 0, 0, 0, 1]
model = [1, 0, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 0, 1]
tmp= [1.81066, 0, 0, 0; 0, 2.41421, 0, 0; 0, 0, -1, 2; 0, 0, -1, 2]

Then i get the output in my post amend above.

Comment: @MatthewHoggan did your comment get cut off? I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Also there is matlab simulator online which can do same thing.